# Show both areas in an area chart where one is missing some values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have some data I'd like to render to an area chart. There are two 'areas', in the data represented as `a` and `b`. `a` has values for all `x` axis values, where as `b` does not. This seems to mean that the area for `b` does not get any fill at all.

Is it possible to have it fill both areas in this situation?

```js
const { Area, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, AreaChart } = Recharts;

const data = [
  { a: [1, 2], b: [3, 5], c: 1 },
  { a: [5, 6], c: 2 },
  { a: [2, 3], c: 3 },
  { a: [1, 8], b: [4, 8], c:4 },
];

const App = () => (
  <AreaChart width={730} height={250} data={data}
    margin={{ top: 10, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
    <XAxis dataKey="c" />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip />
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="a" stroke="#8884d8" />
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="b" stroke="#82ca9d" />
  </AreaChart>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  (<App />),
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/recharts/1.8.5/Recharts.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

---

#### Edit

connnectNulls seems to get part of the way there, but the behaviour is not quite what I was expecting:

```js
const { Area, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, AreaChart } = Recharts;

const data = [
  { a: [1, 2], b: [3, 5], c: 1 },
  { a: [5, 6], c: 2 },
  { a: [2, 3], c: 3 },
  { a: [1, 8], b: [4, 8], c:4 },
];

const App = () => (
  <AreaChart width={730} height={250} data={data}
    margin={{ top: 10, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
    <XAxis dataKey="c" />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip />
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="a" connectNulls stroke="#8884d8" />
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="b" connectNulls stroke="#82ca9d" />
  </AreaChart>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  (<App />),
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/recharts/1.8.5/Recharts.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Does `[0, 0]` fit your demand?

Comment: @keikai Do you mean, would having the values show as [0, 0] fit the demand? Not really; I don't mind the graph rendering a point there, but having it in the tooltip would be a bit misleading